# Daily Arithmetic and daily Geometric Averages for each year (AAPL)

Tags: r, return, quantmod, yahoo-finance, stock

I am trying to obtain the daily arithmetic and daily geometric averages for each year, for the APPL stock data using R. My implementation on this will be the periodReturn function in the last few lines, but it doesn't seem to work, and an error: '...' used in an incorrect context is given.

How can I modify my code such that I can get the desired output? Some help will be deeply appreciated.

```
# Get historical price data (daily)
getSymbols('AAPL', from = "2005-01-01")

AAPLdaily <- as.data.frame(AAPL)
head(AAPLdaily)

?to.period

# AAPLweekly <- to.weekly(to.weekly(AAPL, indexAt = 'endof'))
# AAPLweekly <- as.data.frame(AAPLweekly)
# Better to do it in one step like this:
AAPLweekly <- as.data.frame( to.weekly(AAPL, indexAt = 'endof') )
head(AAPLweekly)

AAPLmonthly <- as.data.frame( to.monthly(AAPL, indexAt = 'endof') )
head(AAPLmonthly)

AAPLyearly <- as.data.frame( to.yearly(AAPL, indexAt = 'endof') )
AAPLyearly

# Another way to do this
AAPLweekly1 <- as.data.frame(to.period(AAPL, period = 'weeks', indexAt = 'endof'))
head(AAPLweekly1)
AAPLmonthly1 <- as.data.frame(to.period(AAPL, period = 'months', indexAt = 'endof'))
head(AAPLmonthly1)
AAPLyearly1 <- as.data.frame(to.period(AAPL, period = 'years', indexAt = 'endof'))
head(AAPLyearly1)


########## Another possible method  ######### 

# Change to data.frames
AAPL = as.data.frame(AAPL)
head(AAPL)

# Get Dates
dates <- as.Date(row.names(AAPL))
head(dates)

# Create a cloumn in APPL data frame with the dates
AAPL$dates <- as.Date(row.names(AAPL))

?aggregate
?substr

# Last Day of month

lastDayofMonth <- aggregate(AAPL["dates"], list(month = substr(AAPL$dates, 1, 7)), max)
head(lastDayofMonth)
AAPLmonth <- AAPL[dates %in% lastDayofMonth$dates, ]
head(AAPLmonth)

# Last day of year

lastDayofYear <- aggregate(AAPL["dates"], list(month = substr(AAPL$dates, 1, 4)), max)
head(lastDayofYear)
AAPLyear <- AAPL[dates %in% lastDayofYear$dates, ]
AAPLmonth

AAPLdaily <- as.data.frame( to.daily(AAPL, indexAt = 'endof') )
AAPLdaily

dailyReturn(AAPLdaily)

periodReturn(AAPL,
             period='daily',
             subset=NULL,
             type='arithmetic',
             leading=TRUE,
             ...
             )
```

Comment: ```yearlyReturn(AAPLdaily)``` is this what you need?

Comment: @GeorgeSotiropoulos Yes, if the output for each year is the daily return for each corresponding year, computed via the arithmetic mean. However, this does not give the geometric mean for each year..

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking for is the yearly, monthly, weekly arithmetic/geometric return all you have to do is:

```
    getSymbols('AAPL',from= '2010-01-01')
    ROC(AAPL[endpoints(AAPL,on = 'years'),"AAPL.Adjusted"],type='discrete’)

2012-12-31    0.32566879
2013-12-31    0.08069493
2014-12-31    0.40622488
2015-12-31   -0.03013708
2016-12-30    0.12480425
2017-09-20    0.36428706
```

for the geometric (log) return change the `ROC` argument to ‘continuous’:

```
ROC(AAPL[endpoints(AAPL,on = 'years'),"AAPL.Adjusted"],type='continuous’)

2012-12-31    0.28191708
2013-12-31    0.07760429
2014-12-31    0.34090873
2015-12-31   -0.03060053
2016-12-30    0.11760902
2017-09-20    0.31063199
```

For other periods change the `endpoints` argument to `months` or `weeks`.

Comment: I am unable to get your above results, even with the quantmod. The following is the output I received:


> getSymbols('AAPL',from= '2010-01-01')
[1] "AAPL"
> ROC(AAPL[endpoints(AAPL,on = 'years'),"AAPL.Adjusted"],type='continuous’)
+